# Loop the query and insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have very simple script that scrapes email from website given in input. I would like to change two things:
have possibility to add more links and put emails into mysql database

```
<?php
  $the_url = isset($_REQUEST['url']) ? htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['url']) : '';
    ?>

    <form method="post">
      Please enter full URL of the page to parse (including http://):<br />
      <input type="text" name="url" size="65" value="<?php echo $the_url;  ?>"/><br />
      or enter text directly into textarea below:<br />
      <textarea name="text" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Parse Emails" />
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['url']) && !empty($_REQUEST['url'])) {
      // fetch data from specified url
      $text = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);
    }
    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['text']) && !empty($_REQUEST['text'])) {
      // get text from text area
      $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
    }

    // parse emails
    if (!empty($text)) {
      $res = preg_match_all(
        "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
        $text,
        $matches
      );

      if ($res) {
        foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
          echo $email . "<br />";
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "No emails found.";
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can get multiple url as comma separated or have + icon to have multiple input box.

Explode in PHP and loop the file_get_contents push email values in an array.

Connect mysql and insert all emails in table as you need

Comment: In `foreach` loop write your insert query, and after making connection run your code.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer works like a charm. I would like also to change insert to textfield and paste there url list and make a loop for every url (take url, take emails, insert, take url, take emails.. etc).